# Java RMI: multiple rmiregistry on the same machine

Tags: java, rmi

We are developing a client-server application with Java RMI and, for testing, we will use a computer both as client and as server. So both the client and the server applications must call rmiregistry on the same machine, but they are two different JVMs obviously. How can we do that? We hoped that it was necessary only to give different ports to LocateRegistry but we get NotBoundException...
What is the correct way?

Answer (score 1):

You can run as many as you like, but why? You don't need to. Have the server start its own Registry via `LocateRegistry.createRegistry()`, and have the client lookup that one. You seem to think the client needs its own Registry, which isn't correct.

If you got a `NotBoundException` clearly either the service wasn't bound at all in any registry, or you looked up the wrong one.

Comment: Ok, but the client too should have its own registry, otherwise how can the server invoke a remote method on the client?

Comment: The client can register itself directly with the server, by providing itself as the parameter to a remote method called on the server, for example `registerClient(RemoteClient client)`. No need for a client-side Registry at all.

Answer (score 0):

RMI Registry is a server which maintains a registry of services.

So your server should connect to the RMI registry and register itself in it, while client should connect to RMI registry and look up your server

So you need to run a *single* RMI Registry on your machine.

It seems that you're getting the NotBoundException cause you have two of them

Comment: "So your server should connect to the RMI registry and register itself in it" what do you mean exactly with thim? a rebind() method?

Comment: I know I have two of them...I would need one for the client and one for the server...they are two different applications, two different JVMs

Comment: You need a single registry which will be used both by server (it will use _bind_ method) and by client (which will use _lookup_ method)

Comment: OK, I have understood up to there but our application is peer-to-peer so the application is both a client and a server

Comment: there's only a single real server which is used for registrations but after it is all peer-to-pper

Comment: @SagittariusA No it isn't. RMI is a client-server architecture.